# Use StringFormat for special output in XAML-Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an integer value named Id and want a Label in Xaml to display the following:

(ID: 160)

I tried the following:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Id, StringFormat='(ID: {0:0})'} />
```

but it doesn't work - it just displays the value of Id:

160

How can I get this working without using a special ValueConverter class?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ContentStringFormat` for content controls instead of the binding's `StringFormat`, has been asked various times before, will have to look for that.

Comment: As i said, for content controls it is ignored...

Comment: Right, my fault - didn't notice that